# Cplusplus cin splitting

Tags: c++, input, stream, cin

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
string input = "";
std::vector<int> board = create_board();
print_board(board);

std::stringstream stream;


cout << "Please enter two numbers: ";
getline(cin, input);
stream << input;
cout << stream << endl << endl;
```

What I want to do is get two numbers from the user separated by a space in the form of a string. Convert them into ints, and store the two ints in an array for further use in the program. (I'm programming the game memory for school in C++). Can someone please help me?

Comment: Why do you want to get the two `int`s in the form of a `string` and then convert later? It'd be much simpler/more efficient to directly read them as `int`s.

Comment: Depends. What is the problem?

Comment: @Tushar - the reasons for reading a line at a time instead of directly reading the individual fields is that it's easier to parse more complicated input formats and it usually makes it easier to recognize and report errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost done.

```
stream << input;
int tmp1, tmp2;
if(stream >> tmp1 >> tmp2)
    cout << tmp1 << " "<< tmp2<< endl;
else
   // there is error.
```

should do it.